# Does this post for "where can we download historical data of Bitcoin" Look OK?

Tags: discussion, triage, disputed-flags

I recently reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50736865/2745495) in Triage as **Unsalvageable** with reason "***Blatantly off-topic*** (this question has nothing to do with programming)". But my flag was disputed because, as I understand it, it eventually [passed as Looks OK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19953812).

Is Looks OK the correct response for this question?

The question is asking for a site/URL/API for Bitcoin historical data. Not only is it not about any specific coding problems, it's asking for an off-site resource making it off-topic for SO. (I checked, and it's not even [on-topic](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Bitcoin SE.)

I just want to understand if I'm reviewing/flagging incorrectly.

Comment: Triage is broken? No... It can't be true...

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up.

This post is definitely off-topic. Review bans have been handed out accordingly.